# Bash - Emacs having trouble opening multiple windows

Tags: linux, bash, emacs, terminal

I'm not sure I'm using the term window correctly in relation to `emacs`, but I am trying to do a homework assignment using `emacs` in a `bash shell`. I want to open `emacs` and have it run in the background while I run `java` files in the terminal and record the results in my open text file.

I know that if you put an Ampersand after your command in `bash`, it will run that process in the background while you do other things. However, when I run

```
$ emacs lab04.txt &
```

emacs does not open. If I then enter

```
$ fg
```

then `emacs` opens up, but it takes up the terminal, it is not in a separate window like what I want. I have also tried several hotkey things inside of `emacs`, including `C-x 4 f` and `C-x 5 f`. One of those splits the screen and I have two windows editing the same file, and the other one opens a new frame, but still in the same window.

I am doing this on my school's `linux serve`r, so I don't think I can edit anything in my .`emacs` file because honestly I have no idea where that even is. Any help would be appreciated! =)

Comment: If you're running in a window system, can't you open Emacs in a new window from a menu?

Comment: What does the `DISPLAY` environment variable contain? That's how Emacs knows whether to open in the current terminal or to use the X Window System to open a new window.

Comment: So it sounds like there's no X display for emacs to use, or else emacs was compiled without X support, and so it's running as a non-GUI program inside the terminal, and you can't run a program that needs foreground terminal I/O "in the background". (You can suspend it and resume it, but if you want to edit something in emacs in a terminal, the emacs process needs to be the foreground job.)

Comment: Tell us how you connect to the linux server, for starters. You might find that you can run a local GUI emacs and use tramp to access the remote files. Alternatively, you can always just open a separate terminal to use for emacs.